# Changing system from stereo to mono

Tags: sound, soundcard

I am trying to configure xdemorse, a morse code decoding software. One of the things I need to do to configure is change my sound settings from stereo to mono. I think I found the answer, I just don't know how to apply it to my specific computer. Here is what I have found.

`pacmd list-sinks | grep name`:
after doing this, the computer gives this as a reply:

```
name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_01.1.hdmi-stereo>
name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo>
```

Then the instructions say to do this:

```
load-module module-remap-sink_name=mono master=alsa_output.pci.0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo channels=2 channel_map=mono,mono
```

But I keep getting this error message: `load-module command not found`. Here is a link to the tutorial I am trying to use. I downloaded gnome alsamixer, but it looks different than the one in the tutorial. [image: gnome alsamixer] Thank you all for your help.

Comment: BTW no one changed the title… [see](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/468531/1)? Must've been a typo.

Comment: I think you forgot to include the URL?

Comment: Sorry about that, your right I forgot. The URL is http://superuser.com/questions/657876/mono-sound-output-in-ubuntu.

Comment: Note that the new command to list available sinks is `paclt list sinks`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Arch wiki [suggests](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples) putting this line into `/etc/pulse/default.pa` for a permanent change. Or, for a temporary change, [you can](https://superuser.com/questions/657876/mono-sound-output-in-ubuntu) use

```
pacmd load-module module-remap-sink_name=mono master=alsa_output.pci.0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo channels=2 channel_map=mono,mono
```

N.B. the second link's format is slightly different, so if this doesn't work, you can try.

```
pacmd load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=mono master=alsa_output.pci.0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo channels=2 channel_map=mono,mono
```

Similarly for the `/etc/pulse/default.pa` method.

Comment: now I get a different error message, Module load failed.

Comment: @BJsgoodlife The same error for all three methods?

Comment: Let's go to a chat room if that is ok. It may be a different question, but how do you use the /etc/pulse/default.pa method?

Comment: I can't chat right now, but I'm not sure I'd be of any use. I'm just google-fuing. The other thing is that you might post up the tutorial that you tried to follow.

Comment: Ok I appreciate all of your efforts, I will continue to look through your information.

Comment: So as per your link, `gksudo gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa`. Did you follow the instructions?