# Is there a way to play a one-sided stereo on both sides?

Tags: sound, video

It's fairly rare these days, but once in a while I bump into a video that has only one-sided sound (only the left channel or only the right channel.) Is there a way for me to change my audio setup so that one side gets played on both sides?

Note that I do not want to download the video, fix it, and play it then. I'd like to just tweak my settings for that one video so the left channel plays on both sides: left and right; or the right channel plays on both sides: left and right.

Changing the balance doesn't help since there is nothing on the other side, it's not a balance problem.

Comment: @MustaphaHadid this question has accepted answer a year ago.. you did not mention anything in comments about why the bounty is offered? what are you expecting? do you have any other problems other than accepted answer?

Comment: @PRATAP I just wanted to drive more attention to the question. I would like to see better solutions. I expect (not sure though) a system-wide solution that targets sound system (like PulseAudio) and not an application-specific solution.

Comment: @MustaphaHadid, This may be what are you looking for: https://askubuntu.com/q/468531/26246 , https://askubuntu.com/q/17791/26246

Comment: @user.dz Exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are talking about video in the browser such as on youtube then I would recommend a plugin. I use Audio EQ for Chrome and I absolutely love it. It allows me to adjust the gain, EQ and make it mono.

Comment: Excellent, that works! I can listen that one video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XOU2ubWkoPw in Mono and hear the sound on both sides.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, system-wide solution using pulse:

1. Get sink list

   ```
   pactl list sinks | grep name:
   ```
2. Use remap module to map channels

   ```
   pactl load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=mono \
    master=<sink_from_prev_cmd> channels=2 channel_map=mono,mono
   ```

To stop it, Unload the module

```
pactl unload-module module-remap-sink
```

For permanent setup, add command from step 2 to `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

**Source:** [Can I downmix stereo audio to mono?](https://askubuntu.com/a/99960/26246)